# Improving an SQLite Query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an event table has around 100k rows in it.
The following complex query on an "event" table and would like to have your opinion on how to optimize this query...

```
SELECT id FROM event 
NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT subj_id, max(timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM event WHERE (
        timestamp >= 1342052128597 AND timestamp <= 9223372036854775807
        AND NOT subj_interpretation = 46))
    GROUP BY subj_id)
GROUP BY subj_id
ORDER BY  
timestamp DESC
```

The query performs here in 0.06-0.07 seconds. Any ideas what good indicies and/or restructures of the query would be.

Currently I am using:

```
CREATE INDEX event_subj_id ON event(subj_id, timestamp, subj_interpretation)
```

And the query plan looks as follows:

```
1 0 0 SCAN TABLE event USING COVERING INDEX event_subj_id (~27777 rows)
0 0 1 SCAN SUBQUERY 1 (~100 rows)
0 1 0 SEARCH TABLE event USING INDEX event_subj_id (subj_id=? AND timestamp=?) (~9 rows)
0 0 0 USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
0 0 0 USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

Comment: `0.06` seconds on 100K rows sounds pretty good to me. What is your actual performance expectation or requirement?

Comment: 0.03 or 0.02   I am pretty sure with a bit of restructuring it could work out

Comment: Eh, you're talking about doubling or tripling the performance of your query.  Have you checked all the usual suspects like proper field indexes?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried restructuring the query to `SELECT DISTINCT id, subj_id, max(timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM event WHERE (timestamp >= 1342055894621 AND timestamp <= 9223372036854775807 AND NOT subj_interpretation = 46)
GROUP BY subj_id
ORDER BY timestamp` but ended up using even more time 0.15s

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your second query by removing the `DISTINCT`, because the `GROUP BY subj_id` already ensures that there cannot be duplicate records:

```
SELECT id,
       subj_id,
       max(timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM event
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1342055894621 AND 9223372036854775807
  AND subj_interpretation != 46
GROUP BY subj_id
ORDER BY timestamp
```

The index itself is already optimal for the `GROUP BY`/`timestamp`/`subj_interpretation` lookup.
However, if you add the `id` column to it, SQLite can use it as a covering index, which removes the need to look up any record in the `events` table itself, which might actually double the performance:

```
0 0 0 SCAN TABLE event USING COVERING INDEX event_subj_id_plus_id
0 0 0 USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

Comment: Dude that is great :D thanks a lot. Also since I am not interested in the subj_id in my returns but only in grouping taking it out made it much faster. Is there a way to have it using the max_timestamp of each subj_id without having to SELECT them.

Comment: You have to use the `max(timestamp)` somewhere. You could try something like `SELECT id + 0 * max(timestamp) ...`, but I doubt this makes much of a difference.